# Removing white space and predefined characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, escaping, preg-replace, trim

I have a variable which has data stored as a string.
I want to remove all occurrences of `\n` and `\u` in the string.
I have tried the usual PHP string command:

```
$var=trim($var)
```

command to remove escape characters, but it did not work, another answer suggested the use of:

```
trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',...
```

However, I still cannot get rid of the characters, is there any other way to do this?

Here is what I am doing:

```
$some_var=trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $var));
$some_arr=preg_split("/(,|:)/",$output);
while ($i<count($arr))
print $arr[i]
```

EDIT1: I need to remove all escape characters, and not any particular string.

EDIT2: current output:-

> '\uBLD_0000_1953\n'

I want to remove the escape characters at the beginning and end of the string. They are not a part of the actual variable

Expected output:

> 'BLD_0000_1953'

Comment: "the usual string command, it did not work" - Provide that as tried.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for your feedback. I have edited the question.

Comment: @john you will receive higher quality answers if you supply some relevant strings with your question.  You want to remove non-ascii characters?  just slashes? The more specific you are, the better answers you will receive.

Comment: @mickmackusa Added an example

Comment: @john Trim has a second argument in which you provide the characters you want it to replace. So pass that one like: `trim($var, "\n\t\r\u");` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method & pattern ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c00d57bfadfdefb7a5b4c2f143a383bc99a1baa)):

```
echo preg_replace("/\\\[bfnrstuv0'\"]/","",'\uBLD_0000_1953\n');
// output: BLD_0000_1953
```

You can expand or reduce the character class as needed.

---

The most literal regex pattern for your question is: `/\\\[nu]/`

---

Smarter still (because the characters to be removed are at the beginning and end of the string) is a non-regex solution suggested by DaGhostman Dimitrov as a comment on the question:

```
echo trim('\uBLD_0000_1953\n',"\\n\u");
// output: BLD_0000_1953
```

Answer (score -1):

There is `preg_replace` function in PHP.

```
$newelement = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$element);
```